# Java does not recognize Comparator Interface

Tags: java

Simply put, i have a Person class and I wish to implement the Comparator Interface. Whenever I do so, my compiler throws an error saying it cannot find that class. Why does this happen?

```
public class Person implements Comparator
{
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private int age;
}
```

Comment: Simply put, please show the code and show the error. Don't paraphrase, else we'll have little to no chance of being able to help you.

Comment: *Why does this happen?*  You did something wrong.

Comment: Person doesn't sound like a right candidate to be implementing the Comparator interface, there is another one called Comparable.

Comment: @Bhesh: you are right. He's probably looking to use `Comparable<Person>`.

Comment: I suppose you might need "import java.util.Comparator // or Comparable"

Comment: You still haven't posted the error message, and you need to do this as it is crucial towards solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `Comparator` here but rather have your class implement `Comparable<Person>`. You would use Comparator for a separate "helper" class, not for the data class itself. If your Person class has a field that would be used to sort it in its "natural" order, then you will do this. Also, don't forget to give the class the necessary method(s) dictated by the interface. You're probably getting your error because you've not done this, but until we see the error message, we can do little but guess.